# How to synchronize between Itemrenderer and component

Tags: list, apache-flex, checkbox, flex4, itemrenderer

I have a List component using Checkbox as ItemRenderer. Now the problem is there is no synch between checkbox and List selection.
When the checkbox is selected/desected, I want to update selectedIndices property of the List and vice versa. The list is allowing multiple selection.

Any sample code for this?

My code is as below:

Assign Itemrenderer in List component:

```
_list.itemRenderer=new ClassFactory(CheckBoxRenderer);
```

CheckBoxRenderer.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:CheckBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
        label="{data.name}"
        selected="{data.isSelected}">
</mx:CheckBox>
```

Comment: Do I understand your situation correctly? You have an ArrayList of Objects each of them has two properties "name" and "selected". You want to be able to control the "selected" property through the List control. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, here is my solution and the [running example](http://it-skills.su/sosamples/webspark46/04_16_combobox/).

I added a data grid to let you see that the data provider is changed after user interaction.

//Application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.events.CollectionEvent;

        [Bindable]private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {name: "record01", isSelected: false}, 
            {name: "record02", isSelected: true}, 
            {name: "record03", isSelected: false}]);

        protected function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            myDG.dataProvider.dispatchEvent( new CollectionEvent(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE));
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:VGroup x="10" y="10">

    <s:List dataProvider="{dp}" itemRenderer="renderers.CheckBoxRenderer" click="onClick(event)"/>

    <s:Spacer height="20"/>

    <s:DataGrid id="myDG" height="120" dataProvider="{dp}">
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name" width="70"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="isSelected" headerText="IsSelected" width="90"/>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:columns>
    </s:DataGrid>

</s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

//Renderer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
            autoDrawBackground="true">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function onChangeEvent(event:Event):void
        {
            data.isSelected = !data.isSelected;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:CheckBox label="{data.name}" selected="{data.isSelected}" change="onChangeEvent(event)"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

**EDIT**

As I mentioned the data grid was added only to show the changes in the data provider.
Here is the code without additional components.

You need to control the data provider through the debuger to see that it is being changed.

[image]

The button was added just to invoke the debugger on trace() line.

//Application without the grid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import renderers.CheckBoxRenderer;

        [Bindable]private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {name: "record01", isSelected: false}, 
            {name: "record02", isSelected: true}, 
            {name: "record03", isSelected: false}]);

        protected function onBtnClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:VGroup x="10" y="10">
    <s:List dataProvider="{dp}" itemRenderer="renderers.CheckBoxRenderer"/>
    <s:Button click="onBtnClick(event)"/>
</s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

**EDIT2**

If you want to restrict the max number of selected items have a look at this code. It works well by me. This time I inserted the itemRenderer in the List definition.

Here is the [working example](http://it-skills.su/sosamples/webspark46/04_16_combobox2/).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" 
           creationComplete="{reculcSelectedCount()}">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        private var _selectedCount:int = 0;

        [Bindable]private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {name: "record01", isSelected: false}, 
            {name: "record02", isSelected: true}, 
            {name: "record03", isSelected: false},
            {name: "record04", isSelected: false}]);

        [Bindable]public function get selectedCount():int
        {
            return _selectedCount;
        }

        public function set selectedCount(value:int):void
        {
            _selectedCount = value;
        }

        protected function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            reculcSelectedCount();
        }

        protected function reculcSelectedCount():void
        {
            selectedCount = 0;
            for each (var item:Object in dp)
            {
                if (item.isSelected)
                    selectedCount++;
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:VGroup x="10" y="10">
    <s:List dataProvider="{dp}" click="onClick(event)">
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <mx:HBox>
                    <fx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                            protected function onChangeEvent(event:Event):void
                            {
                                data.isSelected = !data.isSelected;
                            }
                        ]]>
                    </fx:Script>
                    <s:CheckBox id="cb" label="{data.name}" selected="{data.isSelected}" enabled="{data.isSelected || (!data.isSelected &amp;&amp; (outerDocument.selectedCount &lt; 2))}" change="onChangeEvent(event)"/>
                </mx:HBox>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
    </s:List>
</s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks Anton for your reply. But I am getting the error below :
Could not resolve <s:DataGrid> to a component implementation. I am using Flex SDK 4.0.0 build 14159.

Comment: Is the effect of updating the data provider what you need? I mean the running example. If so, I can change my code to use only mx components.

Comment: The data-grid is changing based on the checkbox selection. But not with the List selection. can we disable the list selection and keep only the checkboxes selectable?

Comment: We can just delete the data grid and the onClick event. I added them only to show that the provider is changed after each interaction. In this case you can see the changes only in debugger, because there are problems with automatic updates of the list components.

Comment: I have just edited my answer. Now you can find a simplified version without the datagrid.

Comment: It works. Thanks. One last thing: I need to restrict the selection to max 2 items. How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Look at my last EDIT in the answer. I added a new working example and the corresponding code.